# R compare with median, into T/F

Tags: r

I am new to R and I would like to ask your help with the following topic.
Sorry that I nv implement the sample, but the dataset is roughly like this but there are more columns and rows.

```
statistic                            total    
#    Subject Min Median   Max        #     row.names    Art   English ...
#1   Art     20    59     70         #1      James       59     61
#2   English 30    55     65         #2      Lloyd       60     55
...                                  ...
```

Compare the (statistic table, median) more(>)than (total table ,each of their subject) into TRUE(1) or FALSE(0)

```
output
#    names      Art         English    
#1   James      0           1
#2   Lloyld     1           0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @akrun it work greatly already thanks a lot ~! :)

Comment: I guess I understand the problem.  There was a bug which I didnt notice before.  I corrected the code.  Hope it works now.

Comment: haha I see the names . Thanks @akrun sorry to bother you, still have 1 more question what if I want to find >=

Comment: If i understand correctly, you can replace `>statistic$Median` with `>=statistic$Median..`

Comment: @akrun93 thanks! not sure why I cant get it when I try >= -.- but it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `order` of `Subject` in `statistic` is the same as the column order in `total`

```
 output <- total
 nm1 <- setdiff(colnames(total), "row.names")

 output[,nm1] <-(total[,nm1] >statistic$Median[col(total[,nm1])])+0
 output
 #  row.names Art English
 #1     James   0       1
 #2     Lloyd   1       0
```

#### Update

If there are `NA` values in the `total` dataset, for example

```
total1 <- total
total1$English[1] <- NA
output1 <- total1
output1[,nm1] <- (total1[,nm1] > statistic$Median[col(total[,nm1])])+0
output1[is.na(output1)] <- 0
output1
#     row.names Art English
#1         1   0       0
#2         1   1       0
```

#### data

```
total <- structure(list(row.names = c("James", "Lloyd"), Art = 59:60, 
    English = c(61L, 55L)), .Names = c("row.names", "Art", "English"
   ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))

statistic <-  structure(list(Subject = c("Art", "English"), Min = c(20L, 30L
 ), Median = c(59L, 55L), Max = c(70L, 65L)), .Names = c("Subject", 
"Min", "Median", "Max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2"))
```

Comment: Hello @akrun its you again! im really glad that you help thanks!forget to mention that some of the value which is 0 is NA in the total table,

Comment: @xavier Are you saying that you want to replace `NA` with `0` in total and then do the comparison?

Comment: I've replaced it to NA in total in order to get the min and median 0> , tried run the code you gave, the output is having some error >.<

Comment: @xavier if there are NA values in total, the output based on my code would return `NA` for that subject.  Then you can convert it to `0` as showed in the update (assuming that the median is >0)

Comment: i'll add the result at the question

Comment: so I check on it, it doesn't really compare with the median